# Querying for multiple work items using TFPT PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I'm trying to query TFS to get the change sets that are linked to a set of work items using PowerShell.  So far I have been able to do that for a single work item using the following command:

```
tfpt workitem 928850 /collection:<collection url>
```

However, I would like to be able to pass in multiple work item IDs at the same time. Does anyone know if this is possible for this command?

I tried pulling multiple work items using a query and the TFPT query command, however it doesn't appear that I can pull linked change sets when using this command.

Comment: On prem or VSO? If it's an on prem TFS instance I can probably help you with a better way to query your workitems by using actual query statements directly against the database. I used to do some reporting for my old team and had to generate weekly spreadsheets based off our TFS workitems, but I don't think my code works for Visual Studio Online instances of TFS (I don't know, it is untested).

Comment: It's an on premise TFS instance, however I don't have direct access to the database.  Only the web interface and through TFS in Visual Studio.

Comment: I should add that I also don't have access to the API, I am only able to use the PowerShell commands through Team Foundation Power Tools (TFPT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got an on prem instance, and can use PowerShell against it, then you should be all set. You're going to need to load the TeamFoundation snapin, and load up a pair of DLLs that should be found in your Visual Studio installation in the path 'Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer'. So, if you have those items you can do this:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Resolve-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll').Path)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Resolve-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll').Path)
$TFS = Get-TfsServer <your TFS URL, something like 'http://MyTFSServer:8080/tfs/MyTeam'>
$WIS = $TFS.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])
```

Once you have a connection to the WorkItemStore you can post queries against it. That is basically the database that stores all your WorkItems for TFS.

```
$QueryText = "SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [ID] = '928850' OR [ID] = '928851'"
$WorkItems = $WIS.Query($QueryText)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Mad Technician, this seems to be working, and pardon my ignorance, but how can I then output the work item information as text?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to output. Have you tried simply outputting `$WorkItems`? If there are fields that you are looking for that aren't included in the base object you can probably find them in the `.Fields` property. Without knowing what you want to output it's hard to help much.